# Как соеденить две строки в одну и сделать так, чтобы функция выполнилась?

Tags: python, datetime

У меня есть словарь к которому надо приписать две последние буквы, чтобы потом вывелось значение.

```
val = days.today

value = val + datetime.date.today().strftime('%A')[:2]

print(datetime.date.today().strftime('%A'))
print(value)
```

Как это сделать правильно? Просто не хочется расписывать огромную конструкцию if elif.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что вы имеете ввиду. Что вы подразумеваете под "приписанием букв к словарю"? Приведите пример входного и желаемого выходного значения

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предположу, что для решения данной задачи помогут f-строки.

```
from datetime import datetime

val = datetime.today()

value = f"{val} {datetime.today().strftime('%A')[:2]}"

print(datetime.today().strftime('%A'))
print(value)
```

OUTPUT:

```
Tuesday
2023-10-03 11:57:14.397156 Tu
```